# Retrofit 2.3.0 always executing onFailure

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit2

i'm trying to send post request using retrofit with @FormUrlEncode, here is my service class

```
import com.dolphithronelab.siastar.response.AuthResponse;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface SIAStarService {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("auth")
    Call<AuthResponse>login(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);
}
```

here is my retrofit client class

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofitClient =null;
    public static Retrofit getClient(String apiserver){
        if (retrofitClient == null){
            retrofitClient = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(apiserver).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        }
        return retrofitClient;
    }
}
```

and here is how i communicate with the api server with ApiKomunikator class

```
public class ApiKomunikator {
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://10.44.7.118/siastar/public/api/";
public static SIAStarService getSIAStarService(){
    return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(SIAStarService.class);
}
}
```

and here how i call from the activity

```
siaStarService.login(mUsernameView.getText().toString(),mPasswordView.getText().toString())
                .enqueue(new Callback<AuthResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<AuthResponse> call, Response<AuthResponse> response) {
                        if(response.isSuccessful())
                        {}
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<AuthResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Gagal koneksi ke server, periksa jaringan internet anda error: "+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        showProgress(false);
                    }
                });
```

when i try to post data via postman, there is no problem, is this because i use static ip or what? and t.getMessage() always null

Comment: add `t.printStackTrace();` and post the stack trace too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a long research, i know that was caused by a timeout connection so i set default timeout on okhttpclient

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
client.setConnectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
client.setReadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
.build();
```